# Derivative of polynomial roots with respect to a parameter

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, parametric, implicit-differentiation

Consider the polynomial

$$p(s;\tau,a)=3(56-56a\tau^2+a^2\tau^4)-112(-6+a\tau^2)\tau s-14(-36+a\tau^2)\tau^2s^2+112\tau^3s^3+7\tau^4 s^4,$$

I want to examine that how the roots of $p$ change with respect to the parameter $\tau$. I determined the derivative of a root with respect to $\tau$ using 
$$ \frac{\partial s}{\partial \tau}(s_i;\tau,a)=- \frac{ \frac{\partial p}{\partial \tau}(s_i;\tau,a)}{ \frac{\partial p}{\partial s}(s_i;\tau,a)},$$
where $s_i$ is one of the roots of $p$.

Is it correct to define the derivative  $\frac{\partial s}{\partial \tau}$? And can we use the implicit function derivative formula?

Comment: While the roots of a polynomial depend on the coefficients in a *continuous* way, the mapping from coefficients to roots is not everywhere *differentiable*.   You can examine what happens where a double real root splits, in one direction going off as two distinct real roots and in another direction as two complex conjugates.

Comment: @hardmath: In my case $\tau>0$ and $0<a \tau^2<28-2 \sqrt 182$. Then $p$ has distinct (negative) real roots. Is the mapping to the roots differentiable in this case?

Comment: Yes, if the roots are distinct and real, then the mapping is locally differentiable.  We should avoid having the denominator zero in your expression of course.